# Which is the best crash logging tool for Windows Phone 8 Apps

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have created Windows Phone app and used crittercism to log exceptions and crashes. Is there any other tool that supports windows phone for logging exceptions and crashes like crittercism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you try the build in crash report from dev center. I think [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2014/09/01/debugging-crashes-of-your-apps-and-games-on-windows-phone-8.aspx) might be helpful for analyse the crash dump data.

Comment: Yes I have seen those stacktrace. But the problem is that it shows exceptions of newtonjson dlls and simpleinjector dlls crashes and I have never seen those exception coming in my app in debug mode. How can i get even detail trace that from which function call and on what data these issue are coming